FileNotFoundError “C:\Workbench\libpostal\src\address_parser.exe”
I am attempting to utilise the pypostalwin package which requires the libpostal library to be installed to my local C drive.
As I am doing so from a work computer and am not overly familiar with unix, I have not been able to navigate proxies and so could not install in through MSYS2 as the package specifies. There is also a Google Drive link listed which could work but I'd need to get approval for which would take a long time.
Instead, I clone the repo of libpostal to my C drive and stored it in a 'Workbench' folder. For all intents and purposes, it appears to be successful but when I try to run the initial steps to configure the python wrapper by passing the White House address, it gives me a FileNotFoundError in “C:\Workbench\libpostal\src\address_parser.exe”.
I had a look into the repo and there are two “address_parser” files, but one is '.c' and the other '.h' extension.
Have I downloaded the repo incorrectly? Is there a way to fix this without relying on MSYS2?

You forgot to show us your code Minimal Reproducible Example

Are you using windows? Then the obvious solution would be to use % symbol between directories

I am, but unsure what you mean by this?

I apologize for being too vague. Use the % symbol to indicate a path. “C:%Workbench%libpostal%src%address_parser.exe”.
